# Retrieve ip address and store in Firestore using scheduler firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

Every 30 min Cloud Function should call (google schedulerCloud Function triggers)
In the trigger, node code retrieve IP address and save it in the  firestore(firebase)
Every time it  retrieved it should store in the current IP field in the firestore.
Every time you should compare the IP . If IP address is the same do nothing.
If Ip changes update current ip and save old ip in previous IP ,
and list array to store log all new IP s using firebase cloud functions using nodejs
My current code
index.js file

```
        exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun((context) => {
       db.collection("getIpAddress").doc("LA").set({
       currIp:request.ip,
        prevIp: ""
        })
      .then(() => {
       console.log("Document successfully written!");
       })
       .catch((error) => {
       console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
       });
       console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
       return null;
        });
```

In this code I am getting request is undefined error.

Comment: Can you please share the code where this `request` value comes from and where it's populated?

Comment: I just want fetch client IP s from request and store it in the firestore.

Comment: this error can happen depending on what the function returns. Can you please share the whole error message and describe how are you fetching the client's IP?